# C++ map: add pair to the end of the map

Tags: c++, std

I am trying to find a faster way to add pairs to the end of a map. Currently, I am adding the pairs at the end of the map and since the key I am using is the index of the for loop which is sorted by default. So I have:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>

int main()
{

        std::map<int, std::set<int> > temp;

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){

                int first[] = {5,10,15,20,25};
                int second[] = {10,20,30,40,50};

                std::set<int> temp2;
                temp2.insert(first, first + 5);
                std::set<int> temp3;
                temp3.insert(second, second + 5);

                std::set<int> temp4;
                std::set_union(temp2.begin(), temp2.end(), temp3.begin(), temp3.end(), std::inserter(temp4, temp4.end()));

                temp.insert(temp.end(), std::pair<int, std::set<int> >(i, temp4));

        }

}
```

When I time this, it takes about 10 seconds. However, when I comment out the line `temp.insert(temp.end(), std::pair<int, std::set<int> >(i, temp4))`, the program takes about 4 seconds to execute. I am wondering why adding the pair to the map takes so much time. Am I doing it in the best way possible?

Comment: You do not need std::set_union(

Comment: A map is a balanced binary tree. If you always insert on the right side the tree will have to rebalance itself on every single insert. A rebalance is probably the worst possible traversal of the entire tree that you can do. You need to make sure that the tree will always be balanced as you insert or it will be slow. In your case a vector is a much better structure because you are using a bounded integer as the key - a vector uses less memory because there are no node pointers like a map has and a vector is contiguous so the prefetcher can cache the data (a map will have many many cache misses)

Comment: One thing aside from the map inserts that could save you some time. Use the range based `std::set` [constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/set/), rather than the `insert` member function. e.g. `std::set<int> temp2(first, first + 5);` for me that shaved of about a second from the running time.

Comment: @DieterLücking why don't i need std::set_union(?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For starters, this is not just some puny little pair. It's a pair that contains an entire container.

Albeit a small container. But it is already populated, and the act of inserting it into another container means that this entire container will need to be copied.

But more importantly, a `std::map` is not a vector that has amortized constant insert complexity. It is typically some variation of a balanced tree, [typically a red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) on most C++ implementations.

This means that repeated `insert()`s at the very end of the map, whether hinted or not, will often require the entire tree to be rebalanced. This is not a cheap operation. And, by repeatedly inserting keys that are always ordered at the end of the key space, the poor map has to keep rebalancing itself, over and over again.